# python: nicer base 'object' for multiple inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, multiple-inheritance

Recently I've tried to play a bit with multiple class inheritance (in Python 3), which I never did before (never had really the use for it).

And I was surprised how "bad" it is. It is not behaving as I was expecting. I understand the MRO and order resolution, but unless I'm missing something, the design does not allow extra parameters to be present at the end of the chain.

Let me give a basic example:

```python
class BaseA(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs.pop('is_cool', False):
            self.a = True
        else:
            self.a = False


class FixedBaseA(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.pop('is_cool', False):
            self.a = True
        else:
            self.a = False
        # if you move super to the top (see BaseA), MyThing instances will raise an error
        # Note: instead of having super down here, one could have explicitly extracted
        # the keyword 'is_cool' in the definition of __init__ method
        # --> __init__(self, *args, is_cool=False, **kwargs)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class BaseB(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs.pop('is_cool', False):
            self.b = True
        else:
            self.b = False


class MyThing(BaseA, BaseB):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class FixedMyThing(FixedBaseA, BaseB):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class FixedMyThing2(BaseB, FixedBaseA):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class MyThing2(BaseB, BaseA):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

As you probably guessed, the behavior I'm wishing for is:

- no matter what order I give for BaseA and BaseB in the inherited classes, I would end-up with the attributes `a` and `b` properly set, and no error
- giving extra parameters would not raise an error

Of course this is not the case. Here are some tests:

```python
def test(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        x = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        print('{:} --> a, b = {:}, {:}'.format(cls.__name__, x.a, x.b))
    except TypeError as err:
        print('[ERR] {:} raised a TypeError: {:}'.format(cls.__name__, err))

test(MyThing, is_cool=True)
test(FixedMyThing, is_cool=True)
test(MyThing2, is_cool=True)
test(FixedMyThing2, is_cool=True)
test(FixedMyThing2, z=3.4)
```

which gives:

```python
[ERR] MyThing raised a TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
FixedMyThing --> a, b = True, False
[ERR] MyThing2 raised a TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
FixedMyThing2 --> a, b = True, True
[ERR] FixedMyThing2 raised a TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

Now my question is not about why this is happening, there are explanations that could be found on the web. While I'm in no position to judge theses reasons, I'm wondering why the `object` type/class is not behaving differently by accepting any extras parameters.

So the real question: is replacing `object` by the following class a bad idea? And if yes why?

```python
class BaseObject(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            # this is necessary to pass along parameters for next-in-line inherited classes
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        except TypeError as err:
            if err.__str__().startswith('object.__init__() takes no parameters'):
                pass
            else:
                raise
```

Using this class in place of `object` everywhere allow to swap order of classes that logically could be swapped (ie. they do not overlap in their attributes / methods), and would allow the use of extra parameters without any trouble at all, but still raise errors whenever it should.

```python
MyThing --> a, b = True, True
FixedMyThing --> a, b = True, False
MyThing2 --> a, b = True, True
FixedMyThing2 --> a, b = True, True
FixedMyThing2 --> a, b = False, False
```

Any thoughts on this  would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in Python 3 you do not need to inherit from `object`. That was only for Python 2; it's done implicitely now.

---

> I'm wondering why the object type/class is not behaving differently by accepting any extras parameters.

I am not sure what you mean here.

- If you are you asking why `object` does not take any parameter, it's because it has no use for them. And raising an error is always better than silently ignoring an unexpected situation. (“*Errors should never pass silently. Unless explicitly silenced.*” -- The Zen of Python)
- If you are asking why your classes accept extra arguments: it's because you explicitely allowed them, using `*args, **kwargs`.

---

> So the real question: is replacing object by the following class a bad idea? And if yes why?

Yes, because you are silently ignoring an error.

---

Generally, using `*args, **kwargs` is not recommended, unless you are using a lot of arguments, or you are writing a middleware library (ie. which passes arguments from a library using yours to a library you use).

Instead, you should rewrite `BaseA` like this:

```
class BaseA(object):
    def __init__(self, is_cool=False):
        super().__init__()
        if is_cool:
            self.a = True
        else:
            self.a = False
```

The same is true for your other classes.

---

Now, more off-topic remarks:

You can clean up `BaseA` further, because you are using Python 3:

```
class BaseA(object):
    def __init__(self, is_cool=False):
        if is_cool:
            self.a = True
        else:
            self.a = False
```

And you can even remove the unnecessary disjunction:

```
class BaseA(object):
    def __init__(self, is_cool=False):
        self.a = is_cool
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes the examples could be cleaner of course, I just wrote them quickly. I agree that errors should not be ignored silently, but in the case of `object`, I don't see the point raising an error: it just means that one must consume all arguments before reaching `object`. While `*args, **kwargs` use is not recommended, it is perfectly valid and is very useful for flexibility and middlewares as you mentioned. But `object` more or less prevent using them. It think this should be left to the coder, and this would be more consistent with the rest of Python (eg. functions)